# User rights needed to provision IBM Cloud Kubernetes Service

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-kubernetes, iks

I am trying to understand what userrights "exaclty" are needed for a user in the IBM Cloud, to being able to provision a Kubernetes Cluster / Container Registry ! Can someone pls depict the rights (admin, editor, etc..) rights per service to successfully provision and run a Kubernetes Cluster. 
Are there ANY rights to be set in the softlayerportal too ?
any hints widely appreciated.
BR Thomas

Comment: Do you mean the IBM Kubernetes Service or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find all the permissions that you need in this doc section: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/containers?topic=containers-clusters#cluster_prepare

Specifically:
- super user in Softlayer
- admin platform role in IBM Cloud Kubernetes Service
- admin platform role in IBM Cloud Container Registry

Comment: Rachel, thank you so much - exactly what I was looking for !! BR Thomas